# No option to run Java 9 project in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, java-9, java-module

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here, I started working on a java 10 project (which of course uses java 9's new module system) so I suspect it has to do with that.

I have the following project directory structure:

[image]

However, the run button in IntelliJ is grayed out and it looks like intellij doesn't recognize this as being a properly structured Java project.

I've looked through the documentation, but a lot of it is circular explanations which cause more confusion than clarity.

I see that the .idea directory has a modules subdirectory which looks like it contains some relevant stuff - I'm probably doing something wrong here, but I don't know what.

Here's my build.gradle file, since I suspect this will be important here:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'application'
    id 'idea'
}

group 'com.chrismailloux'
version '0.1'
description = "Tutorial application developed to learn LWJGL and OpenGL."

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) {
    gradleVersion = '4.9'
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Dependencies left out for brevity
}
```

Can someone set me straight here? How can I fix this to be able to run the project?

Comment: How did you create/started the project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The default folder structure in Gradle is `src/main/java`, but you use `src/$project-name/main/java`. I suspect that without further configuration, Gradle does not know where to find the sources and thus IntelliJ doesn't know either.

It looks like source sets ([1](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_source_sets), [2](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/building_java_projects.html#sec:java_source_sets)) are the answer:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/$project-name/main/java'
        }
    }
}
```